# Blender render by F12, the result is weird, but view point render is good(simple flag with cloth and wind)

Tags: rendering, animation

It's a fluttering flag, and the view point is rendered well.
But the F12 render result is weird, there 's strange lines and jagged something.

Why?

This is the view point render result(cycles)
[image]

This is the render result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have subsurf modifier before cloth, that's has different levels for viewport and render. The numbers should be the same:

[image]